# Filtering objects from array by a property, using the method filteredArrayUsingPredicate

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nspredicate, predicatewithformat

I can't understand how to use predicate, I have a very long code to filter objects from array by property "type" and suddenly I saw method "filteredArrayUsingPredicate" that can make my life better. I try write predicates but I always get errors; can someone show me how to write it right?

I have method `- (void) filterData: (NSString *)filteredWord`:

I also have array with objects (Event): **NSArray *eventsArray**. 
I want use a filteredArrayUsingPredicate to get new array with objects (Event) where their property (type) is equal filterWord. Note that Event is Core Data Managed subclass.

Is it even possible to do this with predicate?

One of my attempts:

```
NSString *propertyName = @"type";
NSArray *eventsArray = [[[[self currentPerson] events] objectEnumerator]allObjects];
NSPredicate *predicte = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%k like '%@'",propertyName,filteredWord];
[eventsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicte];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *propertyName = @"type";
NSArray *eventsArray = [[[self currentPerson] events] allObjects];
NSPredicate *predicte = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                         @"%k like %@",propertyName, filteredWord];
NSArray *filteredArray = [eventsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicte];
```

You ignore the filtered result. The `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`
   returns a *new* instance of `NSArray`. It doesn't filter the original
   array in place, because `NSArray` objects are immutable. You either
   have to make an
   [`NSMutableArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
   and then use `filterUsingPredicate:` to filter the array in place, or
   you have to do something with the returned array of
   `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` (log it, save it etc...)

Don't use single quotes around the property. (thanks for the clue @MartinR)

Comment: thank you for your comment I think I understand little bit about predicts.. but in some reason filteredArray has 0 objects when I am sure that there more then one objects with filtered type.

by the way I use `[[array objectEnumerator] allObjects]` because events are NSSET.

Comment: In that case you can use `[set allObjects]`. No need for an enumerator. Also, the type property of UIEvent is not a string. It's an enum (integer). See my updated answer.

Comment: Actually, "%K" can also be used instead of "SELF.%@". "%K" is a var arg substitution for a key path in predicates. - And I happen to know (from Dennis' previous questions) that `Event` is a Core Data managed object subclass and not related to `UIEvent`. So "%K LIKE %@" should work.

Comment: @DrummerB same, 0 objects, the type is string and I think the first answer was better that this because in the first one I used enumerator to get array of Events, predicate as I understand filter "Event.type == "filteredWord" Events that good entered to filteredArray the problem is that not really happened. maybe something wrong with the predict or transfer to the new Array?

Comment: Martin R you right I forgot say that Event is a Core Data Managed object, I will edit my question.

Comment: Add an `NSLog` of your predicate format, the original and resulting arrays to your question. `NSLog(@"your predicate format", propertyName, filteredWord);` and `NSLog(@"Original:\n%@\nResult:\n%@", eventsArray, filteredArray);`.

Comment: @DrummerB ok, I got as expected SELF.type LIKE 'Wedding' (when I use @ not K).
the second line I get some parameters=nil (I don't work with them yet) and type = Wedding in some objects.. (my filteredWord).

when I use: 

NSString *propertyName = @"type";
    NSArray *eventsArray = [[[[self currentPerson] events] objectEnumerator]allObjects];
    NSPredicate *predicte = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                             @"SELF.%K LIKE '%@'",propertyName,filteredWord];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[eventsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicte]];

Comment: @Dennis: Don't enclose `%@` in quotation marks in the predicate format string!

Comment: Martin you are a king, DrummerB thank you very very much for your help here :)

Just to understand what the different between %@ and '%@'?
by the way I use %K but %@ works too.

Comment: @Dennis: Format specifiers in quotation marks are not replaced, so `LIKE '%@'` searches for the (verbatim) string "'%@'".

Comment: ok, thanks.

@DrummerB I mark your answer as right, If you can back your last answer with this little changes for other users that have this problem.

thank you..